# adding image into code

Tags: html, image

Can someone give me feedback on this: Made the code using a third party image host (i've used them before). When I put the code in where I want it on the page (after checking on google inspect) it doesn't show up at all.

```html
<div id="header"> <img src="preview.ibb.co/n25Rcy/banner_18.jpg"; width="920" height="174">
```

Comment: Your question is too vague. Code means a lot of things. Do you mean html?  Use an <img > tag.

Comment: not sure why the upvotes? This can be googled fairly easily .. ? `Including external images on website html` ?

Comment: yes html. See my code above your comment

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I did google search but cant seem to find out why my code isn't working?  I need some professional feedback. Do you have any solutions?

Comment: @Michelle https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Images_in_HTML - was third result .. scroll down (or use CTRL + F for find) to get embed images ..

Comment: know this already- looking for help with my specific code

Comment: @Michelle and if you read properly you would see the protocol part (absolute url's usage) for external images and your code would work ..

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the protocol at the start of the url (I used https in the code below).

```html
<div id="header"> <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/n25Rcy/banner_18.jpg"; width="920" height="174">
```

Comment: "protocol"? I already have the <div id="header"> before the image code so not sure what you mean?

Comment: oh yes of course! Well i copied this code and uploaded but still nothing showed in website

Comment: The div before the img is actually an element itself, like the img that you have. The protocol is a part of the url, in this case we're talking about the url you use in the src attribute of your img element. Here, the url used in the src attribute needs to have the `https` part, otherwise it won't be able to get the image at that url.

Comment: Are you able to check the console to see if you get any errors?